# Can I create a hyperlink inside a code block?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, code-formatting

Suppose I have the following code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Is there a way to make [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) above point to [its documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int main() {
    yes_you_can();
    return 0;
}
```

It requires the use of explicit HTML, though.

```
<pre><code>int main() {
    <a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115029/155556" title="recursion!">yes_you_can();</a>
    return 0;
}</pre></code>
```

Comment: I guess the downside of using explicit HTML is that you don't get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Oof, that's ugly though. I knew about the HTML approach but didn't realize that characters on the following line would hide the link underlining.

Comment: @PopularDemand: That's probably browser-dependent. It looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: Oh, okay. FF5 Win7 here, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = new [ArrayList]<Integer>();
```

Doesn't seem like you can (see edits to this answer)

But you **can** do:

[`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Which is a link (but the **whole** line)

Comment: Your whole-line example renders identically to just plain old code for me. Seems like the potential for confusion is very high.