# URLs in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting

```
$obj = new Object();
print $obj->getThings();
```

Why not have the ability to linkify `getThings()` or `Object()` within the code block?

I realize this could be a pain to implement in Markdown, but maybe we can find a solution. Perhaps references at the end of the post like:

```
[1,11:8](http://api.url/Object)
```

Where `1,11` is the position of the word that needs to be linkified, and `8` - the length of the word.

Comment: What's wrong with linking them outside the code block?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, but having links inside the code might improve user experience

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115022/162175

Answer (score 8):

You can actually already do this if you **really** wanted to, although not many people expect to find links *inside* the code.

```php
$obj = new Object();
print $obj->getThings();
```

I don't see a Markdown equivalent being useful, though.

Comment: Whine whine syntax highlighting gone whine whine

Comment: can you also post instructions on how to achieve this?

Comment: @OneTrickPony: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/192a435f-a1a2-4cce-9857-842b15c02e31/view-source

Comment: Ah nice, now I know who to blame if this starts to spread..... :)

Comment: I wouldn't use that, but I'd still like to have this feature

Comment: You can [blame @hammar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115029/162175).