# Allow the creation of links in formatted code through markdown or the GUI

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks, code-formatting, editor

As pointed out in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115022/can-i-create-a-hyperlink-inside-a-code-block#answer-115029) it is possible to create a link in formatted code. But, only by using explicit HTML. Since I think creating a link to documentation within a code block is a fairly common use case, it should be possible to do this using the GUI.

I should be able to highlight some code. Press the [image: code format button] code formatting button. Then highlight some code within that and press the link button and create a link.

Today this results in:

```
[parseInt][3]("01", 10);
```

it should result in:

```
parseInt("01",10);
```

Comment: So. How would you differentiate that from a multidimentional array? =D

Comment: `Since I think creating a link to documentation within a code block is a fairly common use case` I've never needed to do that.  If I want to post a link to documentation it'll usually be in the explanation before or after the code block.

Comment: @Servy That is what I do too. But, if it were easy to link to docs from within a code block I would do it.

Comment: Oh no, one mistake in your Objective-C and all hell breaks loose. Let's please leave the code-blocks as pure as possible.

Comment: Can't see much use for it. If there is a link in a "code block" then it's "code" not a link.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure I like this suggestion.

Whenever I've needed to throw some code into the mix with a reference, I would write a blurb about the code block, including a link to the API, *then* use the code in action.

I don't see a reason to mix code with links.  Code is code.

Answer (score 1):

A link title with code formatting is possible, as when you are linking to the docs for a particular class or function:

```
You should use [`-[NSString rangeOfString:options:]`][1] for this, passing [`NSLiteralSearch`][2] for the `options:` argument.
```

becomes:

> You should use [`-[NSString rangeOfString:options:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_options_) for this, passing [`NSLiteralSearch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW8) for the `options:` argument.

I think this is sufficient. (Note: Meta doesn't style links differently, but mouseover those first two code-formatted bits and you'll see the links.) Putting links into larger code blocks doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Code needs to be exact; mixing up some other language with makes editing more confusing than it needs to be. (It also makes the mouse selection target touchier -- dammit, I was trying to highlight the text, not click the link!)

As a bonus, putting links in the English text outside the code block encourages you to do a little explanation, too, which nearly always increases the answer's quality.

I don't have any great positive argument as to why this *shouldn't* be done; it's more that I think there's no need for it. Leave the code blocks for the machine.