# Dollar Sign corrupts question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

In https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions my question ([Which is easier/cheaper: Hbridge vs ESC for controlling a motor?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/985/which-is-easier-cheaper-hbridge-vs-esc-for-controlling-a-motor)) contains a "$" in a quoted section of the question.  Originally I had a second "$" in a second quoted  section of the same question.

However when I did this the second $ seemed to trigger a style that made the text italic and lost spacing between words.  I took out the second "$" and instead emphasized it with the word "dollars" which solved the immediate problem.

However, in the listing of the question, (not the question itself) the same thing happens after the first "$".  The summary shows the text without spaces between words and in italic.

Seems like a bug.

Below is a verbatim copy/paste of the original issue (two dollar signs):

---

I was able to find a small ESC for about $12 off of ebay.  If you were designing a robot, would you see that and think?

> $12 bucks for an ESC that connects to simple pulse-wave interface -
>   sign me up!

Or would you think:

> $12 just to control a motor? I could throw together an H-bridge for
>   $0.50 and be done with it.

My robot in particular actually has two motors and therefor $24 to control the two of them.  But the interface is really easy (plus has the added advantage of being R/C vs computer controlled with a simple change of connectors.

Which way would you go?

Comment: Money always corrupts everything </obligatorySnark> ;)

Comment: Money corrupts. Absolute money, um... no, wait.

Comment: @JoshCaswell D'oh! Beat you by TWO seconds!

Comment: You guys are definitely fast!

Comment: That's the second time I've had that happen today, @Andrew!

Comment: Addressing the _actual question_ for a second, could you reproduce, inside a code block, the original text that caused the strange formatting, along with the new text? Kind of like I did in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165750/159251).

Comment: It looks like MathJax is being triggered because the line breaks don't appear in the question excerpt, which is probably problematic.

Comment: It looks like this is "by design" but in the throws of understanding the issue we uncovered another bug.  Does this need to asked in form of a new question?  See discussion in answer from @hayden

Comment: [throes](http://www.onelook.com/?w=in%20the%20throes%20of&ls=a), @ChronoFish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing latex, it allows you to write math equations in your questions and answers.
*(though this is not enabled on all sites, and in particular not on meta!)*

For example, writing $x^2$ will display (prettily) x squared (with the 2 super script).

**You can write an ordinary $ sign by writing \$ (backslash dollar).**

*Note: the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site also uses this, see [this post on how to use it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).*

Comment: I'll check this out...hang on

Comment: Okay - that"worked" but introduced a new bug.  The first $ works fine.  When viewing the question, the 2nd works fine.  Although there is enough of a delay that I can see the \$12 get over-written.  In the question list however, the first $12 is fine and the second holds the escape ("\")

Comment: @ChronoFish it takes a small amount of time to render it, so I think that is "normal" :)

Comment: I don't have a problem with it... just noting that is what I see.

Comment: However, that doesn't excuse the "\$12" I'm seeing in the list of questions.  The second $ is causing issues, not in the question itself, but in the list of questions.

Comment: @ChronoFish That is indeed strange, that bit could be a bug?

Comment: So does this need to be opened up as a new question in order to be treated as a "bug"?

Comment: @ChronoFish I think the so, since your question asked what was going with the dollar-sign, rather than the specific second dollar display issue (which you found after) :)

Comment: New bug question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169422/dollar-sign-corrupts-list-of-questions-may-be-latex-related