# Dollar Sign corrupts list of questions (may be latex related)

Tags: bug, markdown

During the discussion of [Dollar Sign corrupts question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169049/dollar-sign-corrupts-question/169050#comment500033_169050) we determined that $ needed to be escaped on sites that have LATEX enabled.

However, when escaping multiple $, we found that initial \$ was fine, but that the second one maintained the "\".

The specific site was https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions

As of this writing, the post in question is the second from the top.  Contributors to my initial meta-site question and I believe this to be a bug.

[image]

Comment: [No repro.](http://imgur.com/RT2JRi7)

Comment: @Makoto: Are you saying you can't reproduce the problem or that you don't see the existing problem?

Comment: Given that I have multiple `\$`, I am able to escape every one of them and maintain the use of `$` for inline math.  I can't reproduce your problem.  Unless you have a specific example, that is...

Comment: When you view the actual question  you will see that the "\" is resolved correctly.  It's only in the list of questions where the second "\" is displayed.