# Dollar signs breaks formatting of 'Hot Network Questions'

Tags: bug, hot-questions, mathjax

Related to [Dollar Sign corrupts list of questions (may be latex related)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169422/dollar-sign-corrupts-list-of-questions-may-be-latex-related) and [Dollar Sign corrupts question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169049/dollar-sign-corrupts-question/).

This [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61467/if-icann-only-charges-0-18-per-domain-name-why-am-i-paying-10):

[image]

looks like this in the 'Hot Network Questions' section of e.g. [astronomy.stackexchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

I think Latex formatting of question titles should be disabled if the question comes from a site that don't use Latex formatting.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231262/148099